# Calling macdef macro within the .netrc file

Tags: ftp, macro

I get this error:

> Unknown .netrc keyword $download

The script reads:

```
machine **.gov
login anonymous
password none

macdef download
        cd  some directory
        quit

$ download
```

Comment: You are correct:

Comment: The approach I now took (thank you to someone for a previous answer).

Comment: I create a .netrc file with login information. I then add in a bash script file ftp ftp.my.site <<EOF (calling the .netrc file).  Then add separate lines for ftp commands, and end with EOF

Comment: I wrote it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

`man 5 netrc` make no provision for macro call, only macro defintion.

way to solve :

```
ftp prep.ai.mit.edu <<EOF
$ download
EOF
```

with

- `.netrc` having login for prep.ai.mit.edu
- `$ download` is actual call to macro defined in `.netrc`

Answer (score 1):

`man netrc` writes,

> If a macro named `init` is defined, it is automatically executed as the last step in the auto-login process

It looks like this is what you need,

```
machine WHATEVER.gov
login anonymous
password none

macdef init
        cd "/some/directory"
        get …whatever…
        quit
```